# Find and replace on Evernote web app

Tags: evernote

On the Evernote web app, is there a way to find and replace text?

I can use the inbuilt find tool in my browser (Chrome) by pressing Ctrl + F, but I can't work out a quick way to *replace* text as well, given there doesn't seem to be an obvious option in the app.

Is there an option I'm not seeing, or even a hacky way to do this that doesn't involve opening up a text editor and copy pasting?

Googling for this leads to Evernote forum posts about using the Evernote Mac or PC application, which do have find/replace available, but unfortunately I can't find anything regarding this feature on the web app.

Comment: +1, my problem too. I guess it's not possible...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "hacky" way: a Chrome extension that lets you find / replace what's in a web page. I haven't used this extension so I can't vouch for its quality, but in principle it should accomplish what you're looking for:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/find-replace-for-text-edi/jajhdmnpiocpbpnlpejbgmpijgmoknnl?hl=en-US